# Open all html files in a directory in multiple browser types with new tab for each file

Tags: html

I'm trying to test a html file in all browsers. Is there a way using the command line to open all of the .html files in a directory in Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, etc with each file in its own tab in each browser to ensure that the html files are working properly across all internet browsers?

This code I have below opens all of the html files but each in a new window for each browser. I'm trying to consolidate all of the files to stick to one browser window.

```
@echo off
setlocal

pushd "C:\pathtohtmlfiles"

for %%a in (*.htm *.html) do (

start "Internet Explorer" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" "file://%CD%\%%a"

start "Firefox" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "file://%CD%\%%a" 

start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "file://%CD%\%%a"

)

popd
```

Comment: You want an IE tab, a FF tab, a Chrome tab...in one browser?  That is not possible.

Comment: lolwut ... you want to combine the different programs into one. good luck with that

Comment: `with each file in its own tab in each browser`: seriously, can you guys read?

Comment: In a perfect world I would have all three browsers open in one program window, but I know what's attainable and what's not. NobleUplift thanks for reading thoroughly and correcting the others.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a command-line argument that is different for each browser.

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL
PUSHD "C:\pathtohtmlfiles"
FOR %%a IN (*.htm *.html) DO (
    REM START "Internet Explorer" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" "file://%CD%\%%a"
    START "Firefox" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -new-tab "file://%CD%\%%a"
    START "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome:\\newtab "file://%CD%\%%a"
)
POPD
```

[Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't have one, so have fun with that. [Here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) are the Firefox command-line arguments and Chrome has no documentation on this.

Comment: The firefox instructions haven't changed anything